# Hamburger Menu on desktop website (with small size icon) for full width and height dropdown on toggle click (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am having difficulty to make my hamburger menu to display a full width and height on toggle button click. I am trying to create a hamburger with small icons positioned left of the screen which when clicked displays a full width and height (transparent) and position the navitems horizontally.

The image of the Hamburger Menu. I only want the icon (the one with white border) displayed without container.

[image]

When this icon is clicked, it displays

[image]

I don't want to display something like this, I want a full width and height with navitems displayed horizontally, also with respective icons. As follow;

[image]

Header.php

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

$container = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php do_action( 'wp_body_open' ); ?>
<div class="site" id="page">

    <!-- ******************* The Navbar Area ******************* -->
    <div id="wrapper-navbar" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">

        <a class="skip-link sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'understrap' ); ?></a>

        <nav class="navbar  navbar-dark bg-primary">

        <?php if ( 'container' == $container ) : ?>
            <div class="container">
        <?php endif; ?>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Toggle navigation', 'understrap' ); ?>">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- The WordPress Menu goes here -->
                <?php wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'theme_location'  => 'primary',
                        'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                        'container_id'    => 'navbarNavDropdown',
                        'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                        'fallback_cb'     => '',
                        'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
                        'depth'           => 2,
                        'walker'          => new Understrap_WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
                    )
                ); ?>
            <?php if ( 'container' == $container ) : ?>
            </div><!-- .container -->
            <?php endif; ?>

        </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
        <nav>
            <!-- Your site title as branding in the menu -->
            <?php if ( ! has_custom_logo() ) { ?>

                <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>

                    <h1 class="navbar-brand mb-0"><a rel="home" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" itemprop="url"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" itemprop="url"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>

                <?php endif; ?>


                <?php } else {
                the_custom_logo();
                } ?><!-- end custom logo -->

        </nav>
    </div>
```

I just want to know which of the classes or ids that need to be tweaked. As I have tried everything possible, it is worsening the situation for me.

Answer (score 0):

'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',

Try to change this class to container to get full width

Comment: It didn't work. I think the entire elements are enclosed in the nav, the size of the container is determined by the size of the nav. As I tried to "navbar-expand-md" or "navbar-expand-lg" to the nav, it grows before clicking on the toggle and listed the items which I don't. I want a hamburger menu then when I click on it, it should display navitem arranged 3 columns and 2 rows.